# can't able zoom in out in mobile devices

Tags: html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

I am using the above meta tag to detect the device but I can't use + n - normally we use in the websites, can anyone explain why it is not working? My website url is below,

https://ezybeeaustralia.com.au/index.php?page=item&id=33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of `user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1.0`

Comment: no man i removed i removed user-scalable=no but still the same

Comment: Didi you removed maximum-scale=1.0?

Comment: yes i removed all just using this line <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />